# How to make this sql query? Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql

So imagine that I have this table (qwerty)

```
SectionID|UserID|Number
------------------------
10        150     1
10        140     0
10        130     0
20        150     1
20        160     1
20        165     0
20        130     0
25        150     0
25        170     1
```

The query I want to run is to select all the `usersID` when the `UserID (150)` has the number(1)

Query with error:

```
SELECT UserID 
FROM qwerty 
WHERE SectionID = (SELECT SectionId FROM qwerty WHERE Userid = 150 and Number = 1)
```

Output:

```
150,140,130,160,165,130
```

Comment: have you tried using `where` in the query? :)

Comment: `When the share the same sectionid as that Userid(150) with the number(1)`??? right??

Comment: Like: `SELECT * FROM table Where sectionID in (SELECT DISTINCT sectionid FROM table WHERE userid = 150 and number = 1)`

Comment: i will write here what i tried

Comment: Thank you JNevill! My query was almost the same as yours except the "in" i was using the = operator so it was returning more than 1 value

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for you to use this sub query.
Use only the WHERE in the main query, like this:

```
SELECT UserID
FROM qwerty
WHERE Userid = 150 and Number = 1
```